# Framework for Webservices

Tags: rest, web-services, selenium, automation, ui-automation

I'm an automation test engineer who develops a Java-based framework for automating web applications using Selenium, and recently I got a challenge to develop new project for our backend web services.

I'm good at the coding part and writing individual scripts for validating the web services, but I am not sure how to develop a complete framework for web services (like [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model)).

Can anyone suggest any framework/design patterns which are used for web services automation?

Comment: Its my requirement, we do full length E2E test only back-end services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When developing a framework for web applications (frontend applications), we will use mostly POM and Hybrid.

Since web services will be working in the background we can include them as test steps within the script, or since you have mentioned it is the only requirement for testing web services, we can go with scenario-based framework development.

Identify the scenarios and construct the framework accordingly.

[Cucumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucumber_(software)) is the best for constructing scenario based frameworks.